# Text not centering vertically with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As the title states, I am not able to center my content vertically.
When I inspect the divs, I have this bit of empty space below my divs and I don't know where that is coming from.
Perhaps that's the problem, since when I go into the dev tool styles and put in `<line-height: 3>` it centers.
I don't wish to hardcode things like this, and flex normally works, but I'm totally stumped here.

If you need to see anything else, please let me know!

```css
.table-page-nav-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
 }

.arrow-btn {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.page-index-inner {
  text-align: center;
  width: 244px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  margin: 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-page-nav-wrapper">
    <div class="arrow-btn"><</div>
    <div class="page-index-inner">Why won't I center correctly?</div>
    <div class="arrow-btn">></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: @TannerDolby He is using Sass, so the blocks are correctly formatted.

Comment: @Dom Yes makes sense. The `css` tag was used and no explicit statement of Sass was made so I wasn't sure.

Comment: This is my mistake. I am using Sass. Didn't know it needed to be explicitly stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is centered correctly. The outer div is centered vertically. What you want to achieve is centering the contents of the div vertically.

So either you make the inner div a flex container itself by adding `display: flex` to it and then vertically centering the contents with `align-items: center` or you could just give the inner div a `line-height` of `50px` since the height of it already hard-coded. This will only work with a text without line-breaks.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

As @DOM explained the code is technical correct.

The common missunderstanding is, that flexbox works on the immediate inner elements of the wrapping flexbox-container but not on the childs or the content of this inner elements.

As centered inner grids are typical css tasks: additional to @DOM's solution here is a general css helper class I use and which does the trick. Just add it to `div.table-page-nav-wrapper`:

```
.center_HV,
.center_HV > div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;                
}
```

That works on line breaks too.

Comment: Thanks for the response and insight!